# Google "timeline" visualization errors in ie9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-visualization

I'm using the google "timeline" visualization and have a problem with IE9. The below timeline looks wonderful in Google Chrome, but as soon as I open the .html in IE9;

- The 'Duration' calculation goes all wrong (1905 years for the first, 1907 for the other 3 rows).
- The group names disappear off the left of the chart.
- If I have lots of rows on the timeline it doesn't render at all, i.e. the number of rows exceeds the hight of the chart.

Has anyone else used the "timeline" viz?

Thanks
Jonathan

```
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['timeline']});
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawTimeline2);

function drawTimeline2() {
  var container = document.getElementById('timeline_div_2');

  var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);

  var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();

  dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Name' });
  dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Opted In/Out' });
  dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Start' });
  dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'End' });

dataTable.addRows([[null,null,null,null]
                        ,['Joe Bloggs','Not Opted Out', new Date(1995, 10, 28), new Date(2000, 10, 28) ]
                          ,['Jane Bloggs','Not Opted Out', new Date(1993, 10, 28), new Date(2000, 10, 28) ]
                          ,['Elvis Pesley','Not Opted Out', new Date(1993, 10, 28), new Date(2000, 10, 28) ]
                          ,['Oliver Twist','Not Opted Out', new Date(1993, 10, 28), new Date(2000, 10, 28) ]
                          ]);

  var options = {
    width: 800,
    height: 400,
    timeline: { rowLabelStyle: {fontName: 'Calibri', fontSize: 11 },
                barLabelStyle: { fontName: 'Calibri', fontSize: 11 } }
  };

  dataTable.removeRow(0);
  chart.draw(dataTable, options);
}
```

Comment: I couldn't replicate the problem in IE9: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/W6p9V/

Comment: Interesting, what if you try it in a local .html file?  Could it be the way jsfiddle wraps it which makes it work?

Comment: Even saving it as a local html file, it works fine.  There is nothing special about how jsfiddle wraps it.  If you have problems with your code, it is possible that there is an error elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks, you're right it does work find in a basic html, i should have checked before posting here. It looks like my problem lies elsewhere.  I have a number of them on the same page in collapsable divs, so that could be causing issues.

Comment: If they are being drawn in hidden divs (which is likely what your collapsed divs are), then you could easily have issues with the display which might explain the group names disappearing, but that should not affect the calculated durations or make the charts not draw at all given a large number of rows of data.  The fix for the display issues is to draw the charts before collapsing the divs or to draw them only when the container div is first expanded.

Comment: Thanks, I feel like I'm getting somewhere now. The display:none; on the div was causing the group names to mess up, but as you say, not causing the messed up durations.  Isn't this calculated by the google api though? The bars on the chart are displaying correctly. It seems to only mess up where the date spans the millennium, i.e. 1996 -> 2004 will return 1908 years.

Comment: The duration problem only happens in IE9, no other versions of IE?  Are you entering dates exactly the same way as your code example?